# Why is a nicotinamide-tryptophan combination used to treat affective episodes in a few older clinical trials?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism

At least one of the journal articles that reported on such clinical trials allured to the **nicotinamide-tryptophan pathway** that I assume must be related to the metabolism of tryptophan into serotonin since at least one of [these journal articles](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/155389%E2%80%8E) placed some emphasis on the **serotonin hypothesis of depression**.